# How to avoid indenting comment blocks with vim cindent?

Tags: vim, indentation

I have a comment block such as:

```
/*++
 Blah:
   blah
 Foo:
   foo
 --*/
```

And I'm using the following vim cindent options:

```
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set cindent
set cino=g0,+0,(0,W2
```

If I select that comment block and indent it with `=`, vim turns it into:

```
/*++
  Blah:
  blah
Foo:
foo
--*/
```

Can I tell vim cindent not to indent comment blocks?

Comment: What filetype are you using, and what's the value of the 'comments' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that's possible.

If indent of comments is important to you, I would consider switching the comment style (with `mb:*` in `'comments'`) to this:

```
/*
 * Blah:
 *   blah
 * Foo:
 *   foo
 */
```

Comment: Thanks. Closing this question as it is being opened for quite a while now. This answer seems quite fair to me.